# What is the timeline for the episodes of the The Boys season 1?

Tags: the-boys-2019

I ask this because it seems like relatively little time passes, and yet

> we also have Hughie forming a romantic relationship of some form included (gasp) sex, during this short span.   This would seem to be at odds with the recent loss of his serious girlfriend Robin, who is, ultimately the motivating force behind why Hughie is crusading with the Boys to begin with

**How much time as passed between the start of the series and each of the eight episodes of the first season?**

Comment: Starlight mentions working for Vaught for "a couple months".